# Different RSA Signing between pycryptodome and cryptography

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, pycrypto, pycryptodome

When im trying some crypto library rsa signing in python, I noticed that the signature generated between `pycryptodome` and `cryptography` are different. Here are my code:

**`pycryptodome`**

```
import base64
from Crypto.Hash import SHA1
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15

# Getting data to sign.
plain_path = input('File to sign-> ')
plain = None

with open(plain_path, 'rb') as f:
  plain = f.read()

# Calculating data hash.
digest = SHA1.new()
digest.update(plain)

# Loading private key.
private_key_path = input('Private key path-> ')
private_key = None

with open(private_key_path, 'rb') as f:
  private_key = RSA.import_key(f.read())

# Signing data.
signer = pkcs1_15.new(private_key)
signature = signer.sign(digest)

pass
```

**`cryptography`**

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import utils

# Getting data to sign.
plain_path = input('File to sign-> ')
plain = None

with open(plain_path, 'rb') as f:
  plain = f.read()

# Loading private key.
private_key_path = input('Private key path-> ')
private_key = None

with open(private_key_path, 'rb') as f:
  private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(f.read(), None, default_backend())

# Signing data.
signature = private_key.sign(plain, padding.PKCS1v15(), utils.Prehashed(hashes.SHA1()))

pass
```

And the results (see the `signature` variable content):

[image: pycryptodome]

[image: cryptography]

However, the correct result for my project is the `cryptography` one, but my question is why are they different? Am I using non equivalent code?

Thanks.

Comment: In the pycryptodome example you are hashing `plain` with SHA1. In the cryptography example you are not hashing `plain` at all.

Comment: if i pass 'plain' instead of 'digest' i will get bytes object has no attribute oid

Comment: i think plain is automatically hashed inside cryptography

Comment: no sir, not if you use a `Prehashed` object for the third argument to `sign` The hash oid is taken from this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! How can i do signing without hashing with pycryptodome?

Comment: A couple of possibilities but they're somewhat ugly hacks.

Comment: Okay, thats not a big deal. Please post your comment as answer so i can mark it :)

Comment: Signing without hashing? Hashing is an integral part of the signature generation. You should always hash the data, as part of the signature generation or outside of it, but hashing needs to be performed (or you should not use PKCS#1 which defines signatures with appendix rather than signatures with message recovery, and even with the latter, the data is commonly hashed).

Comment: And as hash function you should definitely not use SHA-1, of course, as it has been broken, especially for signature generation.

Comment: sorry, im not the maker of adb. im just following adb specs. all this just for my adb implementation :)